# Textinput onpress action to move next section

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm working for my app and in its login screen, I want the user to move from 
`username-textinput` to `password-textinput` when the user pressed `enter` button.

```
class Login extends Component {  
    constructor(){ 
        super();        
        this.state = {
            username : "",
            password: "",
            isLoading : false       }   }

    render() {          

        return (
                 <View>

                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Username"
                        onChangeText={ (text)=> this.setState({username: text}) }
                        autoCorrect = {false}                   
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        onChangeText={ (text)=> this.setState({password: text}) }

                    />
                 </View>
                );    } }
```

How can I achieve this? I use React-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Username"
                    ref={(input)=> this.username=input}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this.password.focus()}
                    onChangeText={ (text)=> this.setState({username: text}) } 
                    autoCorrect = {false}                   
                />
                <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    ref={(input)=>this.password=input}
                    onChangeText={ (text)=> this.setState({password: text}) }

                />
             </View>
```

Comment: wow thank you sir. It allows user to go to the password-textinput.

Answer (score 0):

I think the React-native doesn't support imeiOptions so you could try setting `multiline=false` in your textinputs

[React Native TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/textinput.html#content)